# What should I set my gateway and local DNS to?

Tags: networking, router, dd-wrt

I'm using a tp-link router flashed with dd-wrt.
This is my current settings page:

[image]

The gateway and local DNS were originally set to `0.0.0.0` by default, but I read that using `192.168.1.1` might be better.
Is that the best choice?

Comment: What is your goal?

Comment: If your WAN is DHCP, don't set them at all.

Comment: @techraf to have a router that works without any issues. Often when I'm browsing the internet on my nexus 7 pad, the internet will stop working and I have to reset the router to get it to work again. Browsing from an imac computer has no issues. I'm not sure what the problem is, but I thought it might be due to some settings being unset/incorrect in the dd-wrt setup.